# Extracting date from string in R using regex

Tags: r, regex

I have the following data frame:

```
    V1 <- c("path/to/file/filename-Aug-4-2017-_to-Aug-4-2017_otherinfo_.csv", "otherpath/to/file/filename-Aug-18-2017-_to-Aug-18-2017_otherinfo_.csv")
    df <- as.data.frame(V1)
```

And I would like to be able to extract the date (formatted as a date) into a new column called df$Date. I've done something similar before using a combination of regex and `str_extract` like so:

```
    df$Date <- str_extract(df$V1, "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")
```

But I'm not sure how I would do this with the dates in this format and really don't understand Regex enough to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also open to alternative methods or approaches. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a really nice input format and you know the dates conform to `three_letters-one_or_two_digits-four_digits` pattern, you may use

```
df$Date <- sub(".*?\\b([A-Za-z]{3}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{4})\\b.*", "\\1", df$V1)
```

See an [R online demo](https://ideone.com/ybTHSY):

```
V1 <- c("path/to/file/filename-Aug-4-2017-_to-Aug-4-2017_otherinfo_.csv", "otherpath/to/file/filename-Aug-18-2017-_to-Aug-18-2017_otherinfo_.csv")
df <- as.data.frame(V1)
df$Date <- sub(".*?\\b([A-Za-z]{3}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{4})\\b.*", "\\1", df$V1)
```

**Details**

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of...
- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `([A-Za-z]{3}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{4})` - Group 1 (later referred to with `\1` backreference from the replacement pattern):

  - `[A-Za-z]{3}` - 3 ASCII letters
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `.*` - any 0+ chars up to the end of string.

So, replacing it with `\1` only keeps the text captured with the `(...)` pattern part.

If you need more precision (if your input is messier than could be) you may try a verbose regex like

```
df$Date <- str_extract(df$V1, "(?i)\\b(Jan|Feb|Ma[ry]|Apr|Ju[nl]|Aug|Sept?|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\\d{1,2}-\\d{4}\\b")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ptPnLQ/1).

**Details**:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier (inline option)
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(Jan|Feb|Ma[ry]|Apr|Ju[nl]|Aug|Sept?|Oct|Nov|Dec)` - one of the alternatives: `Jan`, `Feb`, `Mar` or `May`, Apr`,`Jun`or`Jul`,`Aug`,`Sep`or`Sept`,`Oct`,`Nov`or`Dec`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: Worked beautifully, and thank you for the details on how the regex works! Incredibly helpful

Comment: Sorry about that, I mistakenly marked the other answer correct. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

A base-R alternative solution:

```
sub(".+(.{3}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{4}).+", "\\1", df$V1)

"Aug-4-2017"  "Aug-18-2017"
```

Explanation:

- First look for four-digit number: `[0-9]{4}`
- It has to be preceded by a hyphen and either one- or two-digit number: `-[0-9]{1,2}-` that is also preceded by a hyphen.
- Finally, just any three character preceding all this: `.{3}` and keep the first match (of everything in the parenthesis) and nothing else.

**EDIT**

A slight improvement based on Wiktor's comments:

```
sub(".{0,}(.{3}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{4}).{0,}", "\\1", df$V1)
```

Comment: It is a poor pattern as it won't 1) find a date at the start (and end, but it is less important) of the string (`Aug-23-2013.csv`), 2) will match some other strings not related to dates like `1xxxx-3-00000000000012013.csv`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/5wWhYq/1). Mind the title says *extracting date*, and the regex above may extract lots of texts that are not even similar to a date.

Comment: Thanks for feedback @WiktorStribiżew, I made an update to accommodate your first example. For the second one, you are right... it can fail this way.

Comment: but in the context of the two examples given, I think this fully solves the problem. Even though as you point out it can fail when taken out of this context.

Comment: In machine learning, this is called "overfitting": yes, it works for the given examples, but it does not generalize well, i.e. it will not work for most of the unseen data.

Comment: Yes. I am not playing down the superiority of your solution. I just wanted to practice, and I think it can also help people to see various different solutions even relatively poor ones.